# Div sometimes vanishes on page load and will only appear on reload or resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having an odd issue that I cannot seem to fix and it's so specific and weird that I haven't been able to find an article that applies.

Here is a JSfiddle that shows the error: http://jsfiddle.net/trqngk10/1/

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var headerHeight = document.getElementById('header').clientHeight;
  document.getElementById("content").style.paddingTop = headerHeight + "px";
  var footerHeight = document.getElementById('footer').clientHeight;
  document.getElementById("content").style.paddingBottom = footerHeight + "px";
}, true);

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  var headerHeight = document.getElementById('header').clientHeight;
  document.getElementById("content").style.paddingTop = headerHeight + "px";
  var footerHeight = document.getElementById('footer').clientHeight;
  document.getElementById("content").style.paddingBottom = footerHeight + "px";
}, true);

function setContentHeight() {
  if (window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight) {
    var headerHeight = document.getElementById('header').clientHeight;
    var footerHeight = document.getElementById('footer').clientHeight;
    document.getElementById("description").style.height = `calc(100% -  ${headerHeight}px - ${footerHeight}px)`;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("description").style.height = "";
  }
  document.getElementById("description").style.top = `${headerHeight}px`;
}

window.addEventListener('load', setContentHeight, true);
window.addEventListener('resize', setContentHeight, true);

$('#nav ul>li').click(function() {
  $(this).find('ul').toggle();
});

$('#footer-nav ul>li').click(function() {
  $(this).find('ul').toggle();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#logo img").hover(function() {
    $("#background").css("background-color", "black");
  }, function() {
    $("#background").css("background-color", "white");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#logo img").hover(function() {
    $("#header").css("background-color", "black");
  }, function() {
    $("#header").css("background-color", "white");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#logo img").hover(function() {
    $("#nav").css("background-color", "black");
  }, function() {
    $("#nav").css("background-color", "white");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#logo img").hover(function() {
    $("#nav ul").css("color", "white");
  }, function() {
    $("#nav ul").css("color", "black");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#logo img").hover(function() {
    $("#footer").css("background-color", "black");
  }, function() {
    $("#footer").css("background-color", "white");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#logo img").hover(function() {
    $("#footer-nav ul").css("color", "white");
  }, function() {
    $("#footer-nav ul").css("color", "black");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#logo img").hover(function() {
    $("h2").css("color", "white");
  }, function() {
    $("h2").css("color", "black");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#logo img").hover(function() {
    $("p").css("color", "white");
  }, function() {
    $("p").css("color", "black");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#logo img").hover(function() {
    $("h3").css("color", "white");
  }, function() {
    $("h3").css("color", "black");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#logo img").hover(function() {
    $("h4").css("color", "white");
  }, function() {
    $("h4").css("color", "black");
  });
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
p {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 17px;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

h3 {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  margin-top: 17px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#background {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
}

a.nonblocklink {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

a.nonblocklinkinp {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

a.nonblocklinkinp:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

a.nonblocklinkterm {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

a.nonblocklinkterm:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

a.blocklink {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  display: block;
}

#header {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
}

#logo {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

#logo img {
  width: 100%;
}

#logo img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%) !important;
}

#nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

#projects {
  display: inline-block;
}

#nav ul {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

#description {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
}

#next {
  display: none;
}

h4 {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: right;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

#nav ul ul {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  list-style-type: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

#nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 75%;
}

#one {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: white;
}

#one:active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#one:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 11;
}

#footer-nav {
  width: 100%;
}

#connect {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#footer-nav ul {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

#footer-nav ul ul {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  list-style-type: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

#footer-nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

#email {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 0px;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: white;
}

#email:active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#email:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#twitter,
#vimeo {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 0px;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: white;
}

#twitter:active,
#vimeo:active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#twitter:hover,
#vimeo:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#instagram {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: white;
}

#instagram:active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#instagram:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#content {
  margin: 0px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  align-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

#content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  #logo,
  #nav ul ul,
  #footer-nav ul ul {
    width: 20%;
  }
  #content-wrapper {
    width: 50%;
  }
  #description {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: 20%;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  #next {
    display: block;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 20%;
    position: fixed;
  }
  p,
  h2 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 17px;
  }
  h3 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Test</h1>
<div id="background"></div>
<header id="header">
  <div id="logo">
    <a href="/" class="nonblocklink"><img alt="A logo." src="images/logo.png"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li id="projects">
        Projects
        <ul>
          <a href="/one" class="blocklink">
            <li id="one">One</li>
          </a>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
<div id="content">
  <div id="next">
    <h4><a href="/one" class="nonblocklinkinp">First Project &#x2192;</a></h4>
  </div>
  <div id="description">
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <p>Test test test test test test test test test test.</p>
    <h3><a href="/one" class="nonblocklinkinp">First Project &#x2192;</a></h3>
  </div>
</div>
<footer id="footer">
  <div id="footer-nav">
    <ul>
      <li id="connect">
        Connect
        <ul>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank" class="blocklink">
            <li id="instagram">
              Instagram
            </li>
          </a>
          <a href="https://vimeo.com/" target="_blank" class="blocklink">
            <li id="vimeo">
              Vimeo
            </li>
          </a>
          <a href="mailto:info@.com" class="blocklink">
            <li id="email">
              Email
            </li>
          </a>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Sometimes 'First Project' will be visible and sometimes it will jump up and presumably be hidden behind my header. Just keep clicking 'RUN' on the fiddle until the 'First Project' appears. If it luckily appears on the first try, refresh the page until it vanishes. Why is this happening? I need it to be visible at all times and be positioned correctly. I would imagine this issue has something to do with my javascript and the order that everything is loading. It seems as if it is originally positioned correctly and then jumps behind my header once the image in my header loads. I'm a beginner in coding, but hopefully one of you masters can see where I'm going wrong!

Also just for some background information, since my header is using an image with a variable size, the header's height depends on the viewing device. Because of this, I have a script that finds the height of the header after the page loads and then sets the content div's (where the 'First Project' is housed) position relative to the height of the header. A little hard to explain, but hopefully you will understand once seeing the code. It was actually such a pain to get right. It is so close to working how I want it.

Some script in the fiddle:

```
function setContentHeight() {
if (window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight) {
var headerHeight = document.getElementById('header').clientHeight;
var footerHeight = document.getElementById('footer').clientHeight;
document.getElementById("description").style.height = `calc(100% -      ${headerHeight}px - ${footerHeight}px)`;
} else{
document.getElementById("description").style.height = "";    
}
document.getElementById("description").style.top = `${headerHeight}px`;
}

window.addEventListener('load', setContentHeight, true);
window.addEventListener('resize', setContentHeight, true);
```

Thanks!

ALSO: one thing I forgot to mention is when the 'First Project' vanishes, it will reappear if you resize the window. This may help you find the issue.

ALSO: the same thing happens to 'TEST' when the viewing device is in portrait orientation. I would imagine whatever the fix is to the landscape issue can be applied to the portrait issue though.

UPDATE: i've removed all css not applicable to the issue. my mistake :)

Comment: Selector `phidden` in your CSS looks broken to me. Did you mean `p.hidden`?

Comment: @KoshVery you can ignore phidden, that was actually css for another page not applicable to this page. my apologies! i'll remove it from the fiddle :)

Comment: Could you please reduce your jsfiddle to a minimal example reproducing your problem?

Comment: @KoshVery absolutely :)

Comment: @JohnSmith I posted a possible solution ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned your code I think the problem was that you was calculating the height before your page was loaded. Also, you called `setContentHeight();` only when the page has been resized not when it was loaded.

```js
let headerNode;
let footerNode;
let contentNode;
let descriptionNode;

let headerHeight;
let footerHeight;

window.addEventListener('load', updateLayout, true);
window.addEventListener('resize', updateLayout, true);

// Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
$(function() {
  console.log('ready!');
  initLayout();
  initHandlers();
  updateHeigth();
  setContentHeight();
});

function initLayout() {
  headerNode = document.getElementById('header');
  footerNode = document.getElementById('footer');
  contentNode = document.getElementById('content');
  descriptionNode = document.getElementById('description');
}

function initHandlers() {
  $('#nav ul>li').click(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();
  });

  $('#footer-nav ul>li').click(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();
  });
  $("#logo img").hover(function() {
    $("#background").css("background-color", "black");
    $("#header").css("background-color", "black");
    $("#nav").css("background-color", "black");
    $("#nav ul").css("color", "white");
    $("#footer").css("background-color", "black");
    $("#footer-nav ul").css("color", "white");
    $("h2").css("color", "white");
    $("p").css("color", "white");
    $("h3").css("color", "white");
    $("h4").css("color", "white");
  }, function() {
    $("#background").css("background-color", "white");
    $("#header").css("background-color", "white");
    $("#nav").css("background-color", "white");
    $("#nav ul").css("color", "black");
    $("#footer").css("background-color", "white");
    $("#footer-nav ul").css("color", "black");
    $("h2").css("color", "black");
    $("p").css("color", "black");
    $("h3").css("color", "black");
    $("h4").css("color", "black");
  });
}

function updateLayout() {
  updateHeigth();
  setContentHeight();
}

function updateHeigth() {
  if (!contentNode) return;
  if (headerNode) {
    headerHeight = headerNode.clientHeight;
    contentNode.style.paddingTop = headerHeight + 'px';
  }
  if (footerNode) {
    footerHeight = footerNode.clientHeight;
    contentNode.style.paddingBottom = footerHeight + 'px';
  }
}

function setContentHeight() {
  if (!descriptionNode) return;
  let newHeight = window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight ? `calc(100% -  ${headerHeight}px - ${footerHeight}px)` : '';

  descriptionNode.style.height = newHeight;
  descriptionNode.style.top = `${headerHeight}px`;
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
p {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 17px;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

h3 {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  margin-top: 17px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#background {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
}

a.nonblocklink {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

a.nonblocklinkinp {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

a.nonblocklinkinp:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

a.nonblocklinkterm {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

a.nonblocklinkterm:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

a.blocklink {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  display: block;
}

#header {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
}

#logo {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

#logo img {
  width: 100%;
}

#logo img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%) !important;
}

#nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

#projects {
  display: inline-block;
}

#nav ul {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

#description {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
}

#next {
  display: none;
}

h4 {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: right;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

#nav ul ul {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  list-style-type: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

#nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 75%;
}

#one {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: white;
}

#one:active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#one:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 11;
}

#footer-nav {
  width: 100%;
}

#connect {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#footer-nav ul {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

#footer-nav ul ul {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  list-style-type: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

#footer-nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

#email {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 0px;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: white;
}

#email:active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#email:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#twitter,
#vimeo {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 0px;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: white;
}

#twitter:active,
#vimeo:active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#twitter:hover,
#vimeo:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#instagram {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: white;
}

#instagram:active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#instagram:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#content {
  margin: 0px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  align-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

#content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  #logo,
  #nav ul ul,
  #footer-nav ul ul {
    width: 20%;
  }
  #content-wrapper {
    width: 50%;
  }
  #description {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: 20%;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  #next {
    display: block;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 20%;
    position: fixed;
  }
  p,
  h2 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 17px;
  }
  h3 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Test</h1>
<div id="background"></div>
<header id="header">
  <div id="logo">
    <a href="/" class="nonblocklink"><img alt="A logo." src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/intel/intel_PNG25.png"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li id="projects">
        Projects
        <ul>
          <a href="/one" class="blocklink">
            <li id="one">One</li>
          </a>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
<div id="content">
  <div id="next">
    <h4><a href="/one" class="nonblocklinkinp">First Project &#x2192;</a></h4>
  </div>
  <div id="description">
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <p>Test test test test test test test test test test.</p>
    <h3><a href="/one" class="nonblocklinkinp">First Project &#x2192;</a></h3>
  </div>
</div>
<footer id="footer">
  <div id="footer-nav">
    <ul>
      <li id="connect">
        Connect
        <ul>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank" class="blocklink">
            <li id="instagram">
              Instagram
            </li>
          </a>
          <a href="https://vimeo.com/" target="_blank" class="blocklink">
            <li id="vimeo">
              Vimeo
            </li>
          </a>
          <a href="mailto:info@.com" class="blocklink">
            <li id="email">
              Email
            </li>
          </a>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: click the **Full page** link to see the snippet.

Comment: Hi @Teocci Thank you so much for your help! I have taken this code and used it in my fiddle, but it seems it is still happening. Where am I going wrong? Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5rv4wpuj/

Comment: I updated a new version that works in jsfiddle also. I recommend you to use it on a html file jsfiddle have some bugs and weird behavior. If I use SO snippet is just to help u to understand how the code works. If this solution meets the requirements please mark it as answered. Thank you.

Comment: You are a legend. Thank you so much. Also, is there any advantage to using the cloudflare link rather than the one I was using?

Comment: You can read more about here. https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/cdn/what-is-a-cdn/

Comment: one last thing, I'm getting an error message on the following line:   descriptionNode.style.height = newHeight;             it's telling me that 'undefined is not an object'    how should I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/osduv.jpg  Here is a link to a screenshot of what I'm seeing :)

Comment: Well this is the last update. I cleaned your code and I leave it to work properly.  You have been using event listeners without a reason or redundantly. Read more about that in this great post. https://eager.io/blog/how-to-decide-when-your-code-should-run/ Happy coding